# Is it possible to run a Linux VM at 1440p with virt-manager?

Tags: linux, resolution, opengl, virt-manager, spice

I would like to run my Linux VM on `virt-manager` at 2560x1440 and not 2560x1080 (closest supported resolution in the VM with virtio without 3D Acceleration and OpenGL).

I tried enabling 3D acceleration, enabling OpenGL support, but then I get an error:

```
SPICE GL support is local-only for now and incompatible with -spice port/tls-port
```

I have the `spice-vdagent` installed on the guest OS and `spice-viewer` on the Host machine.

I am running a Ryzen series chip with integrated graphics if that matters.

What annoys me as well it runs at 50Hz only at 2560x1080

It's a QEMU/KVM VM.